# google script detect empty cell after edit or delete

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a problem with my code. It seems fine but it doesn't work and I really don't know why. I tried everything.

I want sync my google excel with my google calendar. Everything work but now I want make event in calendar when I edit only blank cell:

```
if (e.oldValue == null) { // also tried if(e.oldValue == undefinded)
var date = new Date(dayRange);
cal.createAllDayEvent(
  e.value,
  date,
)
```

}

And it works fine. But next I want delete event from calendar when I delete cell (so it is blank again):

```
else if(e.value==null){
  var events = cal.getEvents(date, {
  search: ss.getRange(row,2)
  });  
  for (i in events){
    events[i].deleteEvent();
}
```

After i "deleted" cell in calendar I get next event with blink title and I don;t know why this event is creating. It seems like this "else if" doesn't work. I really don't know why. I read all example and code seems ok.

This is how I create my trigger:

```
function createEditTrigger() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('ToCalendar')
   .forSpreadsheet(ss)
   .onEdit()
   .create();
 }
```

I will be very grateful for all the advice.

**EDIT**

Full code:

```
function ToCalendar(e) {  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("myID");

    var range = e.range;
    var column = range.getColumn();
    var row = range.getRow();

    var day = ss.getRange(1,column);
    var dayRange = day.getValues();

    if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)) {
        var date = new Date(dayRange);
         cal.createAllDayEvent(
         ss.getRange(row,2).getValue(),
         date,
         {
             description: e.value,//ss.getRange(row, column).getValue(),
         }
        )
     }

    //If we edit cell:

     else if(e.oldValue!=undefined){
        var events= cal.getEventsForDay(date,{search: e.oldValue});
        var ev= events[0];
        Logger.log(ev);
        ev.deleteEvent();
        cal.createAllDayEvent(ss.getRange(row,2).getValue(),date, 
        {description: ss.getRange(row, column).getValue()})


   // If we delete cell   



    else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue != null)){
         var events = cal.getEvents(date, {
         search: ss.getRange(row,2)
       });  
         for (i in events){
            events[i].deleteEvent();
          }

  }
```

Creat trigger:

```
function createEditTrigger() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('ToCalendar')
   .forSpreadsheet(ss)
   .onEdit()
   .create();
  }
```

And screen of my test sheet:
[image: Sheet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to run each function for the case for editing an empty cell and the case for deleting a value of cell. If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? I think that there may be several workarounds. So please think of this as one of them. In this workaround, it supposes that you are using `onEdit(e)`. When the cell is changed, `e` of `onEdit(e)` is changed as follows.

1. In the case for editing a value to empty cell

   - `e.value` is included in `e`.
   - `e.oldValue` is NOT included in `e`.
2. In the case for overwriting a cell with a value by other value

   - Both `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are included in `e`.
3. In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value

   - Both `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are NOT included in `e`.

Using above results, in order to run each function for the case for editing an empty cell and the case for deleting a value of cell, you can use the following sample script.

#### Sample script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (("value" in e) && !("oldValue" in e)) {
    Logger.log("In the case for editing a value to empty cell")
  }
  if (!("value" in e) && !("oldValue" in e)) {
    Logger.log("In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value")
  }
}
```

Of course, you can also use the following script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)) {
    Logger.log("In the case for editing a value to empty cell")
  }
  if ((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null)) {
    Logger.log("In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value")
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- If you want to run the methods which require to authorize, please install a trigger to `onEdit()`.

#### Reference :

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

The syntax errors are removed and modified your script. In this modified script,

- When the empty cell is edited, the script in `if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { script }` is run.
- When the cell with a value is overwritten by a value, the script in `else if(e.oldValue!=undefined) { script }` is run.
- When the value of cell with a value is removed, the script in `else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { script }` is run.

#### Modified script :

```
function ToCalendar(e) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("myID");
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var day = ss.getRange(1,column);
  var dayRange = day.getValues();
  if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { // When the empty cell is edited, this becomes true.
    var date = new Date(dayRange);
    cal.createAllDayEvent(ss.getRange(row,2).getValue(),date,{
      description: e.value,//ss.getRange(row, column).getValue(),
    })

  // In your situation, this might not be required.
  } else if(e.oldValue!=undefined) { // When the cell with a value is overwritten by a value, this becomes true.
    //If we edit cell:
    var events= cal.getEventsForDay(date,{search: e.oldValue});
    var ev= events[0];
    Logger.log(ev);
    ev.deleteEvent();
    cal.createAllDayEvent(ss.getRange(row,2).getValue(),date,{description: ss.getRange(row, column).getValue()})

  } else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { // When the value of cell with a value is removed, this becomes true.
    // If we delete cell
    var events = cal.getEvents(date, {
      search: ss.getRange(row,2)
    });  
    for (i in events){
      events[i].deleteEvent();
    }
  }
}
```

### Added:

It was confirmed that the specification of the event object is changed. The following modification was confirmed. This was mentioned by [@I'-'I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i).

#### From:

- In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value

  - Both `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are NOT included in `e`.

#### To:

- In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value

  - `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are included in `e`.

    - `e.value` is an object like `{"oldValue":"deleted value"}`.
    - `e.oldValue` is a string like `"deleted value"`.

By this modification, when the value was removed from a cell with the value, this can be checked by the following script.

```
if (e.value.oldValue) {
    // value was removed from cell.
} else {
    // value is NOT removed from cell.
}
```

#### Note :

- In the case for editing a value to empty cell and in the case for overwriting a cell with a value by other value, each result is not changed.

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. I tried this way. BTW you have a mistake in second if, I suppose you mean that e.oldValue!=null not ==:). I do like you put and now program doesn't create blank event in calander but this second if also doesn't work :/

Comment: @begginer I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I used ``("value" in e)``, ``!("value" in e)`` and ``!("oldValue" in e)`` as ``(e.value != null)`` , ``(e.value == null)`` and ``(e.oldValue == null)``, respectively. In my environment, it works. When it doesn't work in your environment, can you provide your current script? I would like to resolve your issue.

Comment: No problem we both know how it should be :). I add all code. First if works fine, second if I didn't test and the last one don't work :(

Comment: @begginer I would like to confirm what you want. You want to run ``events[i].deleteEvent()`` when the value was removed from the cell. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly, I want add event to calander if i put value to cell and then when I delete value from cell also remove/delete event from calendar

Comment: @begginer Thank you for replying. And you don't want to use ``"value" in e``. You want to use ``e.value != undefined`` or ``e.value != null``. How about this?

Comment: Both methods are fine for me but  neither of them work  :/

Comment: @begginer In your current script, there are syntax errors in the script. So it is required to be modified. Before modifying your script, I would like to confirm as follows. From your script, when the empty cell is edited, ``((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null))`` become true. When the cell with a value is overwritten, ``(e.oldValue!=undefined)`` is true. When the cell with a value is removed, ``((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue != null))`` is not true. So although it should be ``((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null))``, is these flow what you want?

Comment: @begginer I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? And I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Wow @Tanaike it is really work! But I am a little bit confused why it works when  'e.value' and also 'e.oldValue'  are equal to 'null' in the same time? Logically 'e.oldValue' should be equal to the previous value :). But it works and I am really grateful, can I give you some how some points, reputations or anything that is available in this forum :)?

Comment: I think I hit the correct button, once again thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @begginer I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for your comment. I think that this is an interesting point. In my environment, I could confirm that ``e.value`` and ``e.oldValue`` show ``"new value"`` and ``"actual oldvalue"``, respectively. And ``e.value.oldValue`` is ``undefined``. Although I ran this by creating new Spreadsheet and project, the results were the same. So I thought that this differences might be a change of version of Spreadsheet or the specification. How do you think about this situation? Or if I misunderstand about this situation, please tell me.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for the additional information. By the information, I could understand about the situation. I could also confirm it. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for your support. The information was updated by your discovery. Thank you, too!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is your middle condition, `if(e.oldValue!=undefined)` This is going to pick up cases where e.value is also undefined, but e.oldValue was not, and create an event. So you are never getting to your final case where you expect a freshly erased cell to delete the event.

I think the logic you want here is `if(e.oldValue!=undefined && e.value!=undefined)`

I think part of the confusion is stemming from mixing of null and undefined.

When received from the OnEdit trigger, the value of an empty cell is `undefined`, rather than `null`.

Because javascript evaluates undefined as false, simply checking `if(!e.value)` (if not value) should be sufficient, but if you want to be explicit you can check `if(e.value === undefined)` instead.

Because javascript also evaluates null as false, `null == undefined` as far as javascript is concerned. For clarity, I suggest changing all your checks to either if(!e.value) or if(!e.oldValue), or removing references to `null` and using `undefined` everywhere.  This will make the script a lot more readable, since the current code makes it seem like null and undefined are expected to behave differently.

Comment: I tried it but this solution don't work form me. I think that when I use onEdit function then e.value is undefined/null not like ' '  (I get this when I put e.value to Logger.log()). I am sitting on this like 4 hours so maybe I am writing folly but still it doesn't work :/

Comment: Sorry, I just tested and you are correct, when using an onEdit trigger the empty cell is not blank but rather it is undefined. I'm going to update my answer, even though I see you mention you tried undefined also in your question. Checking vs undefined should work.

Comment: I tried null, undefined everything :) and it still creats blank event in calendar when I delete cell (cell is again blank). Everything seems ok but still it doesn't work and I have no idea where the problem is. I can also put my all code here but I don't think that will help.

Comment: yes I suggest putting up the rest of the code, based on the snippets it seems like it should work.

Comment: on reviewing the whole code this looks like a minor logic error, I've updated my answer

Comment: I don't think it was a main problem because this condition I added later but you make some good point that better write this condition like this. @Tanaike solved the problem but thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Current results(2020) with new `V8` engine suggests that `e.oldValue` is always included, when the cell is deleted or backspaced or each of the character is deleted one by one.

#### Actions:

The following actions are taken one by one and the event object is recorded on each action with

```
const onEdit = e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
```

```
|   | B(Value)      | Action taken               |
|---+---------------+----------------------------|
| 3 | deletedValue1 | deleteFromPC/insertValue   |
| 4 | deletedValue2 | backspaceFromPC            |
| 5 | deletedValue3 | deleteCharacter1by1PC      |
| 6 | deletedValue4 | clearFromMOBILE            |
| 7 | deletedValue5 | deleteCharacter1By1MOBILE  |
| 8 | deletedValue6 | overwriteValue6To6.1MOBILE |
| 9 | deletedValue7 | overwriteValue7To7.1PC     |
```

- `insertValue`: The text "deletedValue1" is inserted into `B3`.
- `autofillInsertedValue`: The text in `B3` is autofilled to `B9`. `B3:B9` contains "deletedValue1" to "deletedValue7"
- `deleteFromPC`: `B3` is deleted using <kbd>Delete</kbd> button.
- `backspaceFromPC`: `B4` is selected and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button is pressed. This fully clears `B4`.
- `deleteCharacter1by1PC`: `B5` is selected> <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed to enter edit mode> Each character is cleared out one by one> <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed again to exit edit mode.
- `clearFromMOBILE`: In mobile app, Options is entered by long pressing and <kbd>clear</kbd> is pressed.(on `B6`)
- `deleteCharacter1By1MOBILE`: Same as above, but from  Mobile.(on `B7`)
- `overwriteValue6To6.1MOBILE`: `B8` value is overwritten from "deletedValue6" to "deletedValue6.1"
- `overwriteValue7To7.1PC`: Same as above , but from PC on `B9`.

#### Results:

The following json provides the `event object` logged by each of the `action` mentioned above. The `action` is used as key of this result object, while the value is the actual `event object` logged.

```
{
  "insertValue": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 3, "rowStart": 3 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" },
    "value": "deletedValue1"
  },
  "autofillInsertedValue": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 9, "rowStart": 4 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" }
  },
  "deleteFromPC": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue1",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 3, "rowStart": 3 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" }
  },
  "backspaceFromPC": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue2",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 4, "rowStart": 4 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" }
  },
  "deleteCharacter1by1PC": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue3",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 5, "rowStart": 5 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" }
  },
  "clearFromMOBILE": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue4",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 6, "rowStart": 6 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" }
  },
  "deleteCharacter1By1MOBILE": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue5",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 7, "rowStart": 7 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" }
  },
  "overwriteValue6To6.1MOBILE": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue6",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 8, "rowStart": 8 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" },
    "value": "deletedValue6.1"
  },
  "overwriteValue7To7.1PC": {
    "authMode": "LIMITED",
    "oldValue": "deletedValue7",
    "range": { "columnEnd": 2, "columnStart": 2, "rowEnd": 9, "rowStart": 9 },
    "source": {},
    "user": { "email": "", "nickname": "" },
    "value": "deletedValue7.1"
  }
}
```

#### Inferences:

- `e.oldValue` key:

  - is present on all events, when cell is deleted(in any way) or overwritten
  - not present, when a empty cell is edited with new value or autofilled.
- `e.value` key:

  - is present, when a new value is inserted or old value is overwritten
  - not present, when value is deleted or cell is autofilled.
- Both `value` and `oldValue` are not present, if cell is autofilled.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not able to get e.oldValue to return the old value when deleting a cell using the delete or backspace key on a Google Sheet as mentioned by @Tanaike:

> - In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value:
>
>   - e.value and **e.oldValue are included in e**.

I could not get e.oldValue to return anything other than 'undefined' and I could not find the answer here, but @Tanaike explains the [solution in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477852/google-script-detect-empty-cell-after-edit-take-2):

---

### The Short Answer:

The results of e.oldValue are determined by whether or not you have formatting applied (cell borders, background shading, etc.) to the edited cell.

---

### Situation 1

If you have the default formatting applied to cell A1 with the text "Sample" in the cell, and you use the delete or backspace key (Mac or PC) to remove the text from the cell, you will get the following result:

**e.oldValue === undefined**.

*Note: if you do not get this result, you may have formatting applied that is not obvious, so use the Format > Clear formatting option and try again.

### Situation 2

If you have formatting applied to cell A1, such as borders, background color, or font (I have tested those 3, but not all other possible options) with the text "Sample" in the cell, and you use the delete or backspace key (Mac or PC) to remove the text from the cell, you will get the following results:

**e.oldValue === Sample**

So, by formatting cells, columns or entire sheets in some way, you can then return and test by the value of an edited cell before deletion.

This behavior can be tested on a blank Google Sheet with the following code:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log("This is the current value in e: " + e.value);
  console.log("This is the Old Value in e: " + e.oldValue);
  if (e.value) {
    console.log("There is a value in e");
  }
  if (e.oldValue) {
    console.log("There is an old value in e");
  }
  if (!e.value) {
    console.log("There is NOT a value in e");
  }
  if (!e.oldValue) {
    console.log("There is NOT an old value in e");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As of 10/21/2019, I no longer find these work arounds to work. When a cell has a value and then that value is deleted with a backspace or delete keystroke, google returns e.oldvalue as expected, but e.value has an odd object in it instead of a falsy response. It's a pretty confusing bug that is really confusing for those trying to automate with gSheets. The new work around now includes checking for data type. Here is a [link to the new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477852/google-script-detect-empty-cell-after-edit-take-2) fully documented including the new work around.

Comment: This should no longer be the case. Everything seems working well now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841681/