# How can I get the oldValue of a cell, when the user deletes cell content? e.oldValue is undefined in this case

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**How can I get the oldValue of a cell, when the user deletes the content?**

The purpose of this is to prevent accidental deletion / edit when novice users use a shared spreadsheet. Only empty cells should be updated without a warning.

It works when editing the content of the cell.
But when deleting the cell content, oldValue is undefined - the cell had content.

PS. I know this only works for single cell edits - I had a check for range width / height == 1, but that is also not true for a value delete. (select cell, press delete)

My test code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log("onEdit called") 
  Logger.log("e.oldValue: %s", e.oldValue) 
  Logger.log("e.value: %s", e.value)
  Logger.log(e) 
  if (!("value" in e) || (e.oldValue != undefined)) {
     if (shouldRevertChange(e.oldValue, e.range.getValue())) {
        e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
     }
   }
}

function shouldRevertChange(oldValue, newValue) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Was this a mistake?',
    'You changed the contents of a cell. Old value: '+oldValue+', new value: '+newValue+'. Do you want to revert the change?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    return true;
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here is my test sheet - editable:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BP0Zqbf8QndhI62AucT3nGNm9eUlgzxf0lTCy2UHe-0/edit?usp=sharing

Also test script:
https://script.google.com/d/1IuTpeEDlsqjDyp3ADRy2JYKzDymR7zOpPkamIcEUHnHXUNdA0SRf7xyU/edit?usp=sharing

I need to see in the alert message, the old value from the deleted cell.

Message for editing value:
[image: User alert]
Logs from editing value:
[image]

Message for deleting / clearing value:
[image]

Logs for deleting / clearing value (old cell value is nowhere):
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.  "e" is an event object e.value is the current "value" of that object or undefined if blank. e.oldValue is the previous "value" of that object.  If the cell contains a value and the user deletes it then oldValue will be the previous value and value is undefined.  If the user puts a value in the blank cell then e.value is that value and e.oldValue is undefined.

Comment: @TheWizEd I think `e` doesn't provide `e.oldValue`, When a cell is deleted. Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548690

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google script detect empty cell after edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548360/google-script-detect-empty-cell-after-edit)

Comment: @TheMaster, if a cell is deleted Logger(e.value) shows {oldValue=1.0} for example.  But notice value in the object is undefined.

Comment: @TheMaster that question does help, but it's not a duplicate - I need to know the value that was just deleted, not just the fact that it was deleted.

I think it's strange that oldValue (of the cell) is not included in the onEdit event, since the cell did have a value before it's deletion.

Comment: I added screenshots and updated the code with new info from the linked question. Now the message triggers correctly, but I don't have the deleted value.

Comment: @Alex In order to include ``oldValue`` in the OnEdit event-object when a value is deleted from the cell including the value, it is required to select the cell and delete the value every character by backspace and delete key. When it selects the cell and delete the value by clicking the key at once, ``oldValue`` is not included. Unfortunately, I think that this might be the specification. In your situation, you want to retrieve ``oldValue`` from this situation. If my understanding is correct, I think that it is required to think of the workaround. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: @Alex You might be able to leverage the Drive API to track the revision history of a Google Sheet document and use it to rollback changes. But it won't  be trivial to implement. If you're up for it you can start with the [Drive API guides](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions).

Comment: You can create a backup sheet, which  essentially makes a exact replica of the original sheet using onEdit. Then, if anyone makes a new edit, prompt and retrieve the last value from backup sheet same cell.

Comment: @Tanaike what workaround do you propose?

Comment: @DimuDesigns Is the Drive API free to use?

Comment: @TheMaster I've seen that before - can I make the backup sheet hidden? Will this work for users editing on mobile also? (if the trigger runs server-side, I assume it should, right?)

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can hide the backup sheet, but it's easy to unhide(not secure). `onEdit()` does work on native mobile apps, but it can't display alerts(Your script will fail or wait forever(6 minutes in Free edition) for user to reply)

Comment: @Alex I think that the good workarounds have been proposed, and those proposals can resolve your issue.

Comment: @TheMaster could I do this: set all cells with a value as protected - in onOpen? Also, is the protected cell message customizable? It would have the same effect as what I'm looking for

Comment: You can just protect the whole backup sheet permanently(without script). People can't edit it. But they still might be able to view it. Or make a copy of your sheet to unhide the sheet etc.. See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765032 has a comment that describes this exact problem. You could star it but that doesn't mean it will get fixed any time soon.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and found a workaround that isn't pretty but it works for me. In my onEdit function I set the background colour of all edited cells to their current background colour, when they are first edited.  
`e.range.setBackgrounds(e.range.getBackgrounds());`  
This stores formatting information about the cell and makes the sheet think of it as "in use". So when you then have a cell selected and click delete, the _oldValue_ will be included in `e`.  
However, this only works on single cell edits.

Comment: @Kajsa, you really should post this as an answer IMHO. I'm still not really sure why it works, but it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: This question is now a exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841681/ and should be closed.  As of 2020, the deleted values are always included in the event object's `e.oldValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin that will accomplish this for you. It takes the route of creating a hidden spreadsheet that mirrors the real one.

https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/73edaed1268a6d07118aed538aa5608d

Comment: Thanks I will try this - does it run for anonymous users also? (not logged in). this will be a public sheet.

Comment: It should, as an anonymous user can create a new sheet normally on a shared sheet if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

```
    function onEdit(e){
        e.range.setNote(e.oldValue);
        e.range.setValue(e.range.getNote());
        e.range.clearNote();
    }
```

The above function uses the 'Insert note' in cell feature of Google 
sheets as a temporary holding variable. A copy of the old value of 
the cell is copied as a note, resets the edited value of the cell 
and the note is deleted. This code does not specifically check if 
the user has hit the 'Delete' key. It replaces any edit made to the 
cell with e.oldValue.

To specifically check if the user has hit the 'Delete' key and reset 
the cell to e.oldValue the function can be changed to:

```
    function onEdit(e){
        if(e.value == null) 
        e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
    }
```

Note: 
Sheets protected via Apps Script are susceptible to edits made via Google Sheets phone app. In such situations, cell formulae may need to be used. Sheet1 may be used to receive user input. Sheet2 is a mirror of Sheet1 and is locked for editing only by the owner. I use the below formula in cell D5 of Sheet2:

```
    =IF(LEN(Sheet1!D5)=0,"Please enter valid input",Sheet1!D5)
```

The user needs to check Sheet2 for the output generated based on input given.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Line to get old value onEdit function

```
var oldValue = e.oldValue ? e.oldValue : null;
```