# Use e.oldValue with delete Key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I am currently working on a time tracking system. With the following code I track the time how long a value was in a cell. This time is recorded in another worksheet and this is done continuously by appendRow ().

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ws = "Tabellenblatt2";
  var ss = e.source;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, 1000, 1);
  var currentDate = new Date();
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws && range != "") {
    var val = e.range.getValue();
    if (val != "") {
      let rowToAdd = [val, "", currentDate, ""]
      ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1").appendRow(rowToAdd);
      ui.alert("Test2");
    } else {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");
      var dataFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(e.oldValue);
      var nameRow = dataFinder.findAll()[0].getRow();
      sheet.getRange(nameRow, 4).setValue(currentDate);
      ui.alert("Test3");
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Currently I cannot delete the content of the cell with the delete key, otherwise e.oldValue is undfined and I cannot get the date in the first worksheet. Now I always have to go to the formula area, mark the text in the cell and delete it. Is there a way to use the whole thing with the delete key anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot have the property `oldValues` if you use <kbd>del</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> button. According to [Tanaike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548690), there are certain scenarios where `values` and `oldValues` would appear in the event object.

> 1. In the case for editing a value to empty cell
>
>    - e.value is included in e.
>    - e.oldValue is **NOT** included in e.
> 2. In the case for overwriting a cell with a value by other value
>
>    - Both e.value and e.oldValue are included in e.
> 3. In the case for deleting a value from a cell with a value
>
>    - Both e.value and e.oldValue are **NOT** included in e.

### Values of event object in multiple scenarios:

**Adding value to an empty cell:**

[image]

**Overwriting a cell:**

[image]

**Deleting a value from a cell with a value:**

[image: Deleted]

A workaround would be creating a macro or button that will save and delete the value of the cell.

### Example:

Code:

```
// this function will delete and display value of the active cell
function deleteCell(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var oldValue = sh.getValue();
  sh.clear();
  Browser.msgBox(oldValue);
}
```

**Button:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

### References:

- [Creating macros in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#creating_macros_in_apps_script)
- [Add A Google Sheets Button To Run Scripts](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/)

Comment: I cannot call the variable oldValue in my addTimeStamp () function, is that even possible?

Comment: @LamaFahrrad - You can but it will return an `undefined` value. Take note that in JavaScript, you can call undefined object without getting error. I added screenshot of the values of event object in multiple scenarios. This will give you a hint on when the property `oldValues` occurs.