# Using Undo(Ctrl+Z) and it's interaction with Google Sheet's Apps Script's onEdit Installable Trigger Event Object e.range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been writing a complex project for my workplace's workflow. Each row on the customer sheet is a product for that customer. The script acts on an installable onEdit trigger based on certain dates being entered into the cells of each customer's spreadsheet. The edits are tested for by column on the customer sheet where each column is "when a step in the process was completed". This occurs on each customers' spreadsheet, and then transfers the data from that edited row into our master workflow Spreadsheet's appropriate sheet for the next step in the process.

Now for my issue. Since the script works based on which column was edited, if the user accidentally edits two columns at once, the script will not transfer the data to the appropriate workflow sheet. This is determined by testing if the event object's range for the edit has a getNumColumns() value of greater than 1. The problem comes when I want to use ctrl+z to revert the change to the previous data that was there before the mistaken 2-column edit. Ideally, the script would skip the part that transfers the row data to the other sheet, because the ctrl+z action would edit the 2 columns that were just wrongly edited. However, the event object's range of the ctrl+z edit only includes the first column of the range that was undone, and the getNumColumns() of this range is returned as 1. Could somebody maybe explain why this is, the inner workings of how the undo action works, or maybe provide me a work-around? I have sufficiently tried to solve this issue on my own, but I need some help

For what it is worth, I have tried using getWidth(). Also, when editing 3 columns at the same time with ctrl+z, the returned event object's range still only includes the first column in the edited range.

PS: The load length stuff is because the customer products are vehicles arriving together in loads

```
function onEditSheet(e)
{
//sets the active spreadsheet as the customer's spreadsheet
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("customersheet");

//sets the active sheet on the customer spreadsheet to the main inventory sheet
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(""),true);

sourceSheet;

//sets the range "range" as the edited range from the event object onEdit(e)
var range = e.range;

/*sets bottomRow to the row of the sheet at the end of the edited range. For example if the 
range was getRange(5,5,5,5), assuming all cells are not blank, would return 10, for row 10 on 
the sheet */
var bottomRow = range.getLastRow();

//sets editedColumn as the left-most row in the edited range
var editedColumn = range.getColumn();

//sets editedRow as the top-most row in the edited range
var editedRow = range.getRow();

/*sets loadLength to the row at the end of the edited range, minus the row at the top of the 
edited range, to find the size for targetRange to use setValues()*/
var loadLength = bottomRow+1-editedRow;

//activates range of source data to test with
sourceSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, loadLength, 54).activate();

//gets the active range of source data
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getActiveRange();

//gets the backgrounds of the sourceRange
var cellColors = sourceRange.getBackgrounds();

//sets data as the array of values within the edited range
var data = sourceRange.getValues();

//sets the target spreadsheet as the Workflow spreadsheet
var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("workflow sheet");

//For some reason this shows as 1 when using ctrl+z
Logger.log(range.getNumColumns());

if(range.getNumColumns()<2)
{

 //Code determining data transfer

}
else
{

//Code showing error box and telling user to use ctrl+z to revert their edit of 2+ columns

}
```

Comment: Probably going to be unreliable now(or in the future),  but you can probably differentiate a ctrl-z edit by looking at `e.value` and `e.oldValue` and sometimes, `e.value.oldValue`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548690/

Answer (score 0):

#### Since your code is incomplete this is as far as I can get

```
function onEditSheet(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "custermersheet") {
  const rg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, e.range.rowEnd - e.range.rowStart + 1, 54);
  rg.activate();//This is kind of pointless
  rg.getBackgrounds();//this does not seemed to be used anywhere
  let vs = rg.getValues();//this is not used anywhere
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("workflow sheet");//This is not used
  let w = e.range.columnEnd - e.range.columnStart + 1;
  if (w < 2) {} else {}//This is incomplete
  }
}
```

Comment: This code will give the same problem as my code. The problem is that when the user edits 2 columns at once using Ctrl+Z, let w = e.range.columnEnd+1 - e.range.columnStart; w equals 1 instead of 2. If you log the range of the edit of 2 columns done with Ctrl+Z, the range returned only includes the first column of the 2-column edit

Comment: Yeah well I need aditional explanation of what you wish it to do because it's really not doing very much and some of the line are not doing anything.  Please read my comments.